# First, last bin in IntervalIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In the following code, for the last bin, rather than specifying 0.38 to 1, is there a way to specify any number larger than 0.38? Also for the first bin, any number that is less than 0.08? (right now, first bin does not include 0 if I put (0,0.08), so I put (-1,0.08) to include 0)

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(-1, 0.08), (0.08, 0.19), (0.19, 0.25), (0.25, 0.38), (0.38, 1)])
df_res['churn_rank']=pd.cut(df_res.churn_rate, bins, labels=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any other way to include the out-of-range values automatically. That's how `pd.cut` is design, i.e. returns `NaN` for those not in range. On the other note, you can simplify your code with:

```
bins = [-np.inf, 0.08, 0.19, 0.25, 0.38, np.inf]
df_res['churn_rank'] = pd.cut(df_res.churn_rate, 
                              bins=bins, labels=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have `include_lowest`

```
df_res['churn_rank'] = pd.cut(df_res.churn_rate, bins=bins, labels=False, include_lowest =True)
```